# Top N values and names (with duplicates) by year

Tags: excel, powerquery

[File picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Yh6.png)I have a table with sales figures by year and sales(wo)man name. I would like to extract the Top N (here top 3 for example) sales figures for a every year and the name of the person. The difficulty is that, for a given year, you can have several times the same name, with different amounts. So the top value for a given year would need to be a sum of all the sales done this year by a particular person.

I tried to use the =SORT(FILTER...LARGE functions mix but it does not sum all the sales done by the same person, it just ranks all the values. I also tried to do it in Power Query but I haven't managed to do the sum of all sales done by one person in a given year too. I am a total beginner regarding Power Query but I am open to solutions using it as it might be more efficient.

Thanks for your help.

[Simplified example[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRLDA.png)

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible sample of your data in a way that it can be copied. Please also post specific examples of what you have already tried. You are giving us nothing to go on.